# How can I implement FIFO queue of threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

How can I implement FIFO queue of threads(tasks to do) and executing the threads one by one?
I mean for example, take the first thread and run it, and the second must wait for the end of execution of the first thread.
At the same time I must be able to add threads(tasks) to the queue.

Comment: If they are to run consecutively, why do you need multi-threading at all? Can't one thread do all the tasks?

Comment: Do you really need them to be Threads? Since you're gonna execute them sequentially I don't see the point... but I don't know the whole story...

Comment: I must use that way becouse is a cpu consuming task and at the same time the system is performing other important job.

Comment: Don't say "thread" when you mean "task".  Threads _execute_ tasks.  I like Vakh's answer and Tucker Down's answer:  Structure your application to use an ExecutorService to perform the tasks, and then, if you want the tasks to be performed serially, choose an ExecutorService that uses only one thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a [FixedThreadPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) with only one thread and submit tasks to it. They will be executed one after the other, like in a FIFO queue:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1); // one thread only
// ...
for(Runnable r : myRunnables) {
    es.submit(r);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As Vakh said, use an ExecutorService to run the threads, however I would recommend using a [SingleThreadExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29). The SingleThreadExectutor is guaranteed to execute threads sequentially because unlike a [FixedThreadPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) it can not be reconfigured to use a different number of threads.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); // one thread only
// ...
for(Runnable r : myRunnables) {
    es.submit(r);
}
```

---

You can also call [Thread.join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) to tell the current thread to block exectution until the other thread dies.

```
Thread t = new Thread(myRunnable);
t.join(); //Wait until t dies
```

There are variations of join which will set a maximum wait time

Comment: I should add, I would have just commented on Vakh's answer but I don't have privileges to do so.

Comment: Iterating the task is a good aproach but, exist a way to verify if the task is queued or executing?

Comment: After adding all of the threads to your executor service you can query them by calling Thread.getState() or Thread.isAlive() which will give you some useful information. Assuming you knew a reference to the threads.

Comment: Or something that didn't occur to me until just now (which is probably more useful), the submit(Runnable r) function returns something called a Future which has a function called isDone() which can tell you if it has finished running yet. In which case you should also familiarize yourself with the Callable interface.

Answer (score 0):

if you want all your threads to run at the same time but you don't want them to use a specific resource or task, then you can use [Synchronized Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)